# JQuery siblings.data() doesn't return the correct value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Html  like :

```
<div class="ajouterContainer" id="ajouterContainer1">
    <div class="ajouter ajoutersaved" id="ajouter1" data-no="1" style='background-image: url(..."); background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);' >
        <div class="pieceModifierContainer"></div>
        <a onclick="return false;" href="#">
            <label>INCLUSION</label>
        </a>
        <span class="pieceFileName">INC-00001_41-H.png</span>
    </div>
    <span class="submenuOpener opened" id="smo1" style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">▼<input type="hidden"></span>
</div>
```

I try to get the data-no attribute of the ajouter1 on click event of ajouterContainer div by :

```
$(".ajouterContainer").on("click", function(event) {
    var itemID = $(event.target).attr('id');
    var itemNumber = itemID.substring(itemID.length - 1);
    var idToFind = "#smo" + itemNumber;
    var openerItem = $(event.target).find(idToFind);
    if (!openerItem.length) {
        $(event.target).css("background-color", "red");
        return;
    }
    //the data-no attribute is 3 by default. I change it using jQuery to 1.
    var dataNo = openerItem.siblings().data("no"); //returns 3
    $(openerItem).prev().attr("data-no"); // returns 1 (the correct value).

});
```

What is wrong with `openerItem.siblings().data("no");` ? 
Before changing it by code, it works.

Comment: when using siblings, it might return several elements and only return the last matched element's data value when reading it

Comment: Thanks for response, but as you see there is only one element who contains data-no. And there is no number 3 in the html code. It can find Something in the cache ?

Comment: A collection of one item. But it's still a collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should filter your siblings using `$(openerItem).siblings('[data-no]').data('no')`

EDIT:

The problem isn't the siblings() method; it's because you're using event.target that takes the child element which is actually clicked and not the `ajouterContainer1`. I've replaced it with `this` which should work for you. I hope this helps:

```js
$(".ajouterContainer").on("click", function(event) {
    var itemID = this.id;
    var itemNumber = itemID.substring(itemID.length - 1);
    var idToFind = "#smo" + itemNumber;
    var openerItem = $(this).find(idToFind);
    if (!openerItem.length) {
        $(event.target).css("background-color", "red");
        return;
    }
    //the data-no attribute is 3 by default. I change it using jQuery to 1.
    var dataNo = openerItem.siblings().data("no"); //returns 3
    console.log(dataNo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ajouterContainer" id="ajouterContainer1">
    <div class="ajouter ajoutersaved" id="ajouter1" data-no="1" style='background-image: url(..."); background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);' >
        <div class="pieceModifierContainer"></div>
        <a onclick="return false;" href="#">
            <label>INCLUSION</label>
        </a>
        <span class="pieceFileName">INC-00001_41-H.png</span>
    </div>
    <span class="submenuOpener opened" id="smo1" style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">▼<input type="hidden"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Yatin. It still returns the old value. But using $(openerItem).prev().attr("data-no");  I can ge the new value. Thanks.

Comment: @CoskunOzogul I have updated the solution and this will help you understand why it wasn't working before. I am sure it will work now. And, I am sorry I took a long time to update this.